# Excel Index function: entered as array, will only return first item of named range used as row ref

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(ISNA(INDEX(ASpreadDataBlocDisplay,ADaysIndex,,1)),"~",INDEX(ASpreadDataBlocDisplay,ADaysIndex,,1)))}
```

ADaysIndex is single column range with the number sequence 1,2,...271.  The numbers are the row numbers.  Entered as array, this formula always returns the first row of the range "ASpreadDataBlocDisplay", i.e. "ADaysIndex" always returns "1".  Is there a method to force the function to return the "ADaysIndex" as a sequence?

N.B.  The formula evaluates correctly if I use a simple cell reference like B15.

Cheers

Comment: Show your input data then desired output.

Comment: In pre-O365 days, to coerce `INDEX` to return an array would require something like `N(IF(1,ADaysIndex))`.